# How to perform 2 operations in MathFilters ( Django )

Tags: python, django

I wanted to perform 2 operations 1: subtract entry_price from Exit_price then multiply the outcome by size. I am getting the error:

```
Could not parse some characters: |(journals.exit_price||sub:journals.entry_price)|mul:journals.size
```

```
<p class="pnl">
    {% if journals.trade_direction == 'Long - Buy' %}
       {{ (journals.exit_price|sub:journals.entry_price)|mul:journals.size }}
    {% else %}
       {{ (journals.entry_price|sub:journals.exit_price)|mul:journals.size }}
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use parentheses in your template variables. Try this:

```
{{ journals.entry_price|sub:journals.entry_price|mul:journals.size }}
```

It will automatically parse from left to right.

Edit: This assumes you have a custom template tag for "sub" and "mul" as those are not built-in.